# I have been trying to Create DataFrame with parse_dates and index_col parameters I keep getting an error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, indexing

```
URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 8
      5 runkeeper_file = 'https://github.com/jbandzo/IBM-DATA-SCIENCE/blob/main/cardioActivities.csv'
      7 # Create DataFrame with parse_dates and index_col parameters 
----> 8 df = pd.read_csv(runkeeper_file)
     10 # First look at exported data: select sample of 3 random rows
```

```
import pandas as pd

# Define file containing dataset
runkeeper_file = 'https://github.com/jbandzo/IBM-DATA-SCIENCE/blob/main/cardioActivities.csv'

# Create DataFrame with parse_dates and index_col parameters 
df = pd.read_csv(runkeeper_file)

display(df.sample(3))


display(df.info())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a path that ends with `csv` but is actually an HTML. Try changing the path `runkeeper_file`  to the raw file, that is -

`runkeeper_file ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbandzo/IBM-DATA-SCIENCE/main/cardioActivities.csv'`

Comment: Hi, I am still getting the same error

Comment: Which pandas version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Change link for raw `csv` first:

```
runkeeper_file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbandzo/IBM-DATA-SCIENCE/main/cardioActivities.csv'
```

Add parameters `parse_dates` and `index_col` by column `Date`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(runkeeper_file, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
out = df.sample(3)
```

Or by first column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(runkeeper_file, parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
out = df.sample(3)
```

Comment: # Import pandas
import pandas as pd

# Define file containing dataset
runkeeper_file ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbandzo/IBM-DATA-SCIENCE/main/cardioActivities.csv'

# Create DataFrame with parse_dates and index_col parameters 

df = pd.read_csv(runkeeper_file, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
out = df.sample(3)

Comment: error message:URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 9
      5 runkeeper_file ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbandzo/IBM-DATA-SCIENCE/main/cardioActivities.csv'
      7 # Create DataFrame with parse_dates and index_col parameters 
----> 9 df = pd.read_csv(runkeeper_file, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
     10 out = df.sample(3)